# Is there any way to delete local commits in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

So I keep making a silly mistake in Mercurial.  Often times, I'll start work without doing an "hg pull" and an "hg update."  When I try to push my changes, I get an error.

Is there any way to delete my *local commits* so I can avoid creating multiple heads, branches, etc?  I just want to delete my local commits, merge my changes with the tip, and then re-commit.  Sounds simple, right?  I can't seem to find any way to easily delete *local commits* so I can cleanly merge with the tip.

Again, I'm only trying to delete local commits made with "hg ci".  I don't want to modify files, revert, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139165/mercurial-delete-all-local-changesets-revert-to-tree

Comment: It's not a silly mistake, it's normal workflow when several people are working with the same repository simultaneously.

Answer (score 263):

Enable the "**strip**" extension and type the following:

```
hg strip #changeset# --keep
```

Where `#changeset#` is the hash for the changeset you want to remove. This will remove the said changeset **including** changesets that descend from it **and will leave your working directory untouched**. If you wish to also revert your committed code changes remove the `--keep` option.

For more information, check the [Strip Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension).

If you get "unkown command 'strip'" you may need to enable it. To do so find the `.hgrc` or `Mercurial.ini` file and add the following to it:

```
[extensions]
strip =
```

---

Note that (as Juozas mentioned in his comment) having multiple heads is normal workflow in Mercurial. You should not use the strip command to battle that. Instead, you should merge your head with the incoming head, resolve any conflicts, test, and then push.

The `strip` command is useful when you really want to get rid of changesets that pollute the branch. In fact, if you're in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2139165/419956)'s situation and you want to *completely remove all "draft" change sets* permanently, check out [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2143711/419956), which basically suggests doing:

```
hg strip 'roots(outgoing())'
```

Comment: @Bharath: You need to enable the extension

Comment: Since mercurial 2.8, strip is a standalone extension, so just ```strip = ``` is fine.
[WhatsNew for Mercurial 2.8](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew/Archive#Mercurial_2.8_.282013-11-01.29)

Answer (score 115):

If you are using Hg Tortoise just activate the extension "**strip**" in:

> 1. File/Settings/Extensions/
> 2. Select **strip**

Then select the bottom revision from where you want to start striping, by doing `right click` on it, and selecting:

> 1. Modify history
> 2. Strip

Just like this:

[image]

In this example it will erase from the 19th revision to the last one commited(22).

Comment: `File/Settings/Extensions/` I wish I could add more votes. Thank you very much!

Comment: Argh!  I tried this but it seemed to dump all my changes despite not checking off "no backup" or "discard local changes".  I wanted to keep those changes, just not commit them!  Is there any way to recover them now??

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to do it properly, but it seems like to keep the content you need to pass `--keep` and TortoiseHg doesn't give that option.  So... you need to do it at the command line with `hg strip -r . --keep`.

Comment: from strip help: 'Any stripped changesets are stored in ".hg/strip-backup" as a bundle (see "hg help bundle" and "hg help unbundle"). They can be restored by running "hg unbundle .hg/strip-backup/BUNDLE", where BUNDLE is the bundle file created by the strip.'

Comment: In the SourceTree it was useful too. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Modern answer (only relevant after Mercurial 2.1):

Use [Phases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases) and mark the revision(s) that you don't want to share as secret (private). That way when you push they won't get sent.

In TortoiseHG you can right click on a commit to change its phase.

**Also:** You can also use the extension "rebase" to move your local commits to the head of the shared repository after you pull.

Comment: Private == secret now

Answer (score 17):

As everyone else is pointing out you should probably just pull and then merge the heads, but if you really want to get rid of your commits without any of the [EditingHistory](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EditingHistory) tools then you can just `hg clone -r` your repo to get all but those changes.

This doesn't delete them from the original repository, but it creates a new clone that doesn't have them. Then you can delete the repo you modified (if you'd like).

Comment: Does "hg clone -r" delete local changes?  I just want to delete local commits to keep things simple.

Comment: It doesn't delete them from the cloned repository, but it creates a new clone that doesn't have them.  Then you can delete the repo you modified if you'd like.

Answer (score 11):

I came across this problem too. I made 2 `commit` and wanted to rollback and delete both commits.

```
$ hg rollback
```

But `hg rollback` just rolls back to the last commit, not the 2 commits. At that time I did not realize this and I changed the code.

When I found `hg rollback` had just rolled back one commit, I found I could use `hg strip #changeset#`. So, I used `hg log -l 10` to find the latest 10 commits and get the right changeset I wanted to `strip`.

```
$ hg log -l 10
changeset:   2499:81a7a8f7a5cd
branch:      component_engine
tag:         tip
user:        myname<myname@email.com>
date:        Fri Aug 14 12:22:02 2015 +0800
summary:     get runs from sandbox

changeset:   2498:9e3e1de76127
branch:      component_engine
user:        other_user_name<name@email.com>
date:        Mon Aug 03 09:50:18 2015 +0800
summary:     Set current destination to a copy incoming exchange

......

$ hg strip 2499
abort: local changes found
```

What does `abort: local changes found` mean? It means that `hg` found changes to the code that haven't been committed yet. So, to solve this, you should `hg diff` to save the code you have changed and `hg revert` and `hg strip #changeset#`. Just like this:

```
$ hg diff > /PATH/TO/SAVE/YOUR/DIFF/FILE/my.diff
$ hg revert file_you_have_changed
$ hg strip #changeset#
```

After you have done the above, you can `patch` the diff file and your code can be added back to your project.

```
$ patch -p1 < /PATH/TO/SAVE/YOUR/DIFF/FILE/my.diff
```

Answer (score 10):

You can get around this even more easily with the [Rebase extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseProject), just use `hg pull --rebase` and your commits are automatically re-comitted to the pulled revision, avoiding the branching issue.

Comment: At the expense of having an inaccurate history and possible corruption if you do things wrong.

Answer (score 6):

`hg strip` is what you are looking for. It's analogous of `git reset` if you familiar with git.

Use console:

1. You need to know the revision number. `hg log -l 10`. This command shows the last 10 commits. Find commit you are looking for. You need 4 digit number from changeset line `changeset: 5888:ba6205914681`
2. Then `hg strip -r 5888 --keep`. This removes the record of the commit but keeps all files modified and then you could recommit them.
   (if you want to delete files to just remove --keep `hg strip -r 5888`

Answer (score 5):

If you are familiar with git you'll be happy to use [histedit](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension) that works like `git rebase -i`.

Answer (score 4):

[Hg Tortoise 4.6.1]
If it's recent action, you can use "Rollback/Undo" action (Ctrl+U).

[image: HG Tortoise Image]

Comment: Double check the inclusion of an image.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Samaursa's excelent answer, you can use the [`evolve`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html) extension's `prune` as a safe and recoverable version of `strip` that will allow you to go back in case you do anything wrong.

I have these alias on my `.hgrc`:

```
 # Prunes all draft changesets on the current repository
 reset-tree = prune -r "outgoing() and not obsolete()"
 # *STRIPS* all draft changesets on current repository. This deletes history.
 force-reset-tree = strip 'roots(outgoing())'
```

Note that `prune` also has `--keep`, just like `strip`, to keep the working directory intact allowing you to recommit the files.