# The default branch has multiple heads due to error adding subrepo

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I managed to get my mercurial repo. into a bit of a state. At Rev 110 I added a subrepo. containing 4 commits to my main repo. however, I made an error when doing this and ended up having two heads on the default branch.

I would like to remove these commits. It is possible to get back to a single head? Or will I have to recreate the entire repo. from scratch?

[image: Screenshot from version control]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to delete local commits in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338986/is-there-any-way-to-delete-local-commits-in-mercurial)

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem!